# How can I check if argument is null, and if not use it in a function?

Tags: dart, null

Is there a shorter, more elegant way to do that?

```
var? x = null == y ? null : foo(y!);
```

Something like this, maybe?

```
int? y = null;
double? x = y?.toDouble() ?? null;
```

(it should be null safe as well)

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/360

Answer (score 3):

No.

There is currently no operation in Dart which takes a value, checks if it is non-null, and if so, does something to it *other* than calling a method on the object.

What you can do, if you want to, is to introduce an extension like

```dart
extension CallWith<T> on T {
   R pipeTo<R>(R Function(T) f) => f(this);
}
```

Then you can write:

```dart
  y?.pipeTo(foo);
```